# how to use default options for product in opencart 2

Tags: opencart2.x

I am using open cart 2.x and now need to add multiple options for every product. Can you advise how can I do it? How do I use use default options for this?

Comment: Have you tried something already? What went wrong? Can you give us something that we can check for mistakes?

Comment: Please read official OpenCart documentation for that. http://docs.opencart.com/catalog/option/

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for default options, you can create them under Catalog > Options, and then just selecting them when creating / editing a product.